# Tensorflow - Sort a tensor with a custom comparator

Tags: python, sorting, tensorflow

How can I sort a Tensorflow tensor of integers with shape [n,2] according to a custom comparison function using only Tensorflow ops?

Let's say that two entries in my tensor are [x1, y1] and [x2, y2]. I want to sort the tensor such that the entries are re-ordered by the condition x1 * y2 > x2 * y1.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you can create a metric (if not, see general case below) for your elements (here, with rearranging the inequality to ***x1 / y1 > x2 / y2***, so the metric will be ***x / y*** and relying on TensorFlow to produce ***inf*** (as in infinity) for division by zero), use [`tf.nn.top_k()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) like this code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant( [ [1,2], [3,4], [1,3], [2,5] ] ) # some example numbers

s = tf.truediv( x[ ..., 0 ], x[ ..., 1 ] ) # your sort condition
val, idx = tf.nn.top_k( s, x.get_shape()[ 0 ].value )
x_sorted = tf.gather( x, idx )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( x_sorted ) )
```

Outputs:

> [[3 4]
>    [1 2]
>    [2 5]
>    [1 3]]

---

If you cannot, or not easily, create a metric, then there is still the assumption that the relation gives you a [***well-ordering***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order). (Otherwise results are undefined.) In that case you build the comparison matrix for the whole set and order the elements by the row sum (i.e., how many other elements are greater); this is of course quadratic in the number of elements to sort. This code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant( [ [1,2], [3,4], [1,3], [2,5] ] ) # some example numbers

x1, y1 = x[ ..., 0 ][ None, ... ], x[ ..., 1 ][ None, ... ] # expanding dims into cols
x2, y2 = x[ ..., 0, None ],        x[ ..., 1, None ] # expanding into rows
r = tf.cast( tf.less( x1 * y2, x2 * y1 ), tf.int32 ) # your sort condition, with implicit broadcasting
s = tf.reduce_sum( r, axis = 1 ) # how many other elements are greater

val, idx = tf.nn.top_k( s, s.get_shape()[ 0 ].value )
x_sorted = tf.gather( x, idx )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( x_sorted ) )
```

Outputs:

> [[3 4]
>    [1 2]
>    [2 5]
>    [1 3]]

Comment: I believe this solution covers the sorting condition `x1 * y1 > x2 * y2`, not `x1 * y2 > x2 * y1` (though this sorting condition seems erroneous to me).

Comment: Oh you're right. `x1 * y2 > x2 * y1` can't that be circular?

Comment: Indeed - just commented OP's post on that matter :)

Comment: Upvoted your comments :) let's hear from him if this is indeed what he intended or if it was a typo

Comment: Why is it circular? This condition can be interpreted as being equivalent to sorting points in a 2D plane in increasing order of their slopes?

Comment: You're right, so basically your condition is `x1 / y1 > x2 / y2`. Updated my answer.

Comment: ... I did get confused too somehow, my bad. Both the question and @Peter answer make sense.

Comment: Never mind, I got confused myself. :) Added a more general way of doing this, albeit that is an overkill for the specific case.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `top_k`Peter Szoldan's answer， there is a `tf.argsort` after 1.13.

For <1.13, use

```
tf.nn.top_k( s, tf.shape(x)[0] )
```

if cannot get the shape in a static graph.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to arrange an input tensor according to a mask, in a way that mask hold information about what indices of the input tensor you are interested in, then this might be useful to you-

```
import tensorflow as tf
inp = tf.constant([
    [7, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0],
    [0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 2]])

mask = tf.constant([
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

order = tf.argsort(mask, axis=-1, direction='DESCENDING', stable=True)
out = tf.gather(inp, order, batch_dims=-1)
print(out)

# tf.Tensor(
# [[7 3 5 0 0 0]
#  [7 9 2 0 0 0]], shape=(2, 6), dtype=int32)
```

In the mask, we have encoded the information about the indices that we are interested in sorting.